# Converting list of tuples in functional way

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I have the following list in Python:

```
[('1','2','3'),('5','6','7')]
```

I need to convert the tuples inside the list into integer(`[(1,2,3),(5,6,7)]`) in a functional way.

I can do them for a list using this simple code: `map(lambda x:int(x),['1','2','3'])`

But how shall i apply the same concept for list of tuples ?

(I know the imperative way of doing this.)

Comment: `lambda x: int(x)` is more simply written as `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tl = [('1','2','3'),('5','6','7')]
[tuple(int(x) for x in t) for t in tl]
# [(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 7)]
```

If you really want the `map` syntax,

```
map(lambda t:tuple(map(int, t)), tl)
# [(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 7)]
```

Comment: map is more efficient that list comprehension (I was surprised too when I first timed one against another)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
[tuple([int(str_int) for str_int in tup]) for tup in list_of_string_tuples]
```

Answer (score 0):

This hybrid works:

```
>>> [tuple(map(int,t)) for t in [('1','2','3'),('5','6','7')]]
[(1, 2, 3), (5, 6, 7)]
```